# Add autorun on startup program in windows embedded ce 6.0 no persistent file system

Tags: windows-ce, autorun

I have a problem with a GPS device: it runs windows embedded ce 6.0 and I am trying to make the GPS software (iGO Primo) run by default (automatically run on startup).

I have tried copying the shortcut to \Windows\Startup folder, but on restart it was gone. I guess it does not have a persistent file system.

Is there a way to check if the registry is persistent? If yes, how can I manually somehow add the line "\ResidentFlash\Primo\Primo.exe" in there to run it on startup?

Running it manually works, so the program is ok, the only problem is I do not know how to automatically run it, I get the Windows interface (desktop & start & co.). Thanks a lot!

Comment: whether you can edit the OS? I mean you can edit BSP source code ? or only application?

Answer (score 2):

In the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Init) you can set your application to launch at startup  Here is the MSDN article related : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924527.aspx

If you need a regedit tool on the device you could use [this](http://www.oohito.com/wince/arm_j.htm).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still working with old win ce devices, the one I worked on had a copy of the windows file system on the flash memory.
Just copy the executable to the Startup folder there and it will run with the next boot.

The path is flash\dramstore\Window\Startup\